# Works in IDE but exe doesn't work (Data gets malformed)

Tags: windows, qt, sockets, qt-creator, qgraphicsscene

My Server draws images/graphic Objects recieved from Client on its `QGraphicsScene` It works well on IDE.

To test in different machines I copied the dlls and the exe in the same folder and ran the exe.
 All network communications went well and I can confirm Client sending graphics Objects But Serevr is not drawing them in `GraphicsScene`

But it works smoothly when I run in QtCReator IDE.

EDIT:

Now it seems image packets gets malformed when running in exe
I did the following to test.

1. Client stores image packets in scan folder
2. Client sends the image packet and makes beep (if successfully saved)
3. Server receives image packets and saves in scan folder
4. server playes beep (if NOT successfully saved)

When I run both (client and server) in IDE

> Client beep's  and server don't 
>   and I see images scan folder of both machines

When I run Client in IDE but server as exe

> Client beeps and stores images 
>   BUT Server beeps and cannot store image in its scan folder

server cannot save the image because `QImage::save()` returns `false`

Comment: Do you need ant environment variable for you app to work ?

Comment: Nope My App Doesn't need any such setup. However I donno If Qt or QGraphicsScene needs

Comment: Can you confirm the server is actually trying to draw stuff? Try adding logging or anything to check if messages are accepted by the server and if the paint/draw routines are being called

Comment: Yes its trying to draw the stuffs and its actually drawing when I run with two phisically different machines. but when I run it in VM it doesn't. I couldn't figure out whats might be the reasoning.

Comment: Oh VM.. hmm are you using OpenGL maybe?

Comment: Nope. Its a plain GraphicsSCene. and even in VM it works under IDE

Comment: What Type of Image You are Transfering ?

Comment: It is JPEG. I've tried different compression which didn't solve the problem

Comment: Ah! I see. Can you re run the same with PNG instead of JPEG ?

Comment: I dunno for whatever reason it shows for sometimes and then it crashes with PNG but when I change it to JPEG it doesn't work at all in exe however it works in IDE with jpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems you are missing the `JPEG` dlls
You need to copy The `jpeg` dlls directory in the folder you are keeping exe. you will find it in your `imageformats` directory `qjpeg4.dll` and `qjpegd4.dll`